# Calculate value and add to new column in new sheet

Tags: excel

I have a sheet with data like a,b,c,d.for each cell,I want caculate result using two formulas and put them in a new sheet like a1,a2,b1,b2,c1,c2...,how to do it? Do I have to use Vba?
the original sheet is a shift table like this:
D is rest,1 is day shift, 2 is night shift. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIXkd.png)

I want to create a new sheet based on this. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hujP0.png)

Comment: You do not need VBA, just use the Excel function `CONCATENATE`

Comment: Can you post a data sample with before and after? It's not clear what you want to achieve. Post a screenshot ,or upload a sample file to an ad free file sharing services like Dropbox or OneDrive.

Answer (score 1):

With data in column **A**, pick any cell and enter:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$4,ROUNDUP(ROWS($1:1)/2,0)) & MOD(ROWS($1:1)-1,2)+1
```

and copy downwards:

[image]

If you want the output in a different sheet, just change the $A$1:$A$4 to point to the proper sheet.